PostgreSQL crosstab query not using view owner permission when queried from other users
I'd like some help with regards to creating a view in PostgreSQL using the crosstab function.
I've been trying to create a view as follows:
create or replace view csv_data as with answers as(
select * from crosstab('select a.column1, q.column2, a.column3 from answer a 
                                join question q on a.question_id = q.id order by 1,2')
as final_result (column1 bpchar, question_1 varchar(500),  question_2 varchar(500), question_3 varchar(500)))
select q.name as "Column1", a.question_1 as "Question1", a.question_2 as "Question_2", a.question_3 as "Question_3"
                            from answers a join evaluation e on e.id = a.eid
                            join questionnaire q on q.id = e.qid
                            where q.active = true
                            order by q.name;

The query above has been slightly modified in order to be in this post, but it does not change the main point in question.
The point being, while trying to perform a select on the view with another user, whose privileges are restricted to a SELECT on such view, I was denied access to the table answer inside the crosstab query. What bothers me is that, the ownership chaining is woking perfectly well in all other cases, only in the query within the crosstab function it does not chain privileges and tries to perform a select using the executing user privileges instead of the view owner.
I'd like to know whether it is possible to solve this issue while still using the crosstab. If not, is there any other way?

As per the recommendation from mustaccio's comment (I don't know how to reference), I'm putting my question update as an possible answer for anyone suffering from the same problem.
Answer
I've been able to solve my problem by creating another view and using it inside the crosstab as it's parameters. By granting a SELECT privilege upon both views I've been able to restrict access up to a degree I've been satisfied with. Still looking for other alternatives though, if anyone knows of a better way.
Example
DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS EXAMPLE BLINDLY AS IT IS MODIFIED AND NOT TESTED AND USED SOLELY AS VISUALIZATION.
CREATE USER restricted_user;

-- Create internal view
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW crosstab_params AS SELECT a.column1, q.column2, a.column3
           FROM answer a JOIN question q ON a.question_id = q.id ORDER BY 1,2;

GRANT SELECT ON crosstab_params TO restricted_user;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW csv_data as with answers AS(
SELECT * from crosstab('SELECT a.column1, q.column2, a.column3 FROM crosstab_params;') -- Use internal view in crosstab
AS final_result (column1 bpchar, question_1 varchar(500),  question_2 varchar(500), question_3 varchar(500)))
SELECT q.name AS "Column1", a.question_1 AS "Question1", a.question_2 AS "Question_2", a.question_3 AS "Question_3"
                            FROM answers a JOIN evaluation e ON e.id = a.eid
                            JOIN questionnaire q ON q.id = e.qid
                            WHERE q.active = true
                            ORDER BY q.name;

GRANT SELECT ON csv_data TO restricted_user;

Once again, this is the solution that worked out for me, but the user will still have access to an extra view. Depending on how you build the internal view query (basically the where clause), there will be no more information being bled, since the internal view has the same informations as the external as it works only as a pivoted table.
